# Is there any way I can use the goto function in my python code?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
    import os,sys

#database
usernames = ["thehappycat123","flyingmonkey265"]
passwords = ["1329pass","6398lol"]

#loginpage
newuser_signup = input("New user? (y/n): ")
if newuser_signup == "y":
    newuser_name = input("New Username: ")
    usernames.append(newuser_name)
    newuser_password = input("New Password: ")
    passwords.append(newuser_password)

if newuser_signup == "n":
    username_login = input("Username: ")

if username_login == usernames[0]:
    password_login = input("Password: ")
    if password_login == passwords[0]:
        os.startfile("assets\secret0.txt")

if username_login == usernames[1]:
    password_login = input("Password: ")
    if password_login == passwords[1]:
        os.startfile("assets\secret1.txt")
```

What I'm struggling with is after making a new user, I want to go directly to the login page but I don't know how to.

Comment: Are you using django or simply a command prompt?

Answer (score 2):

Put the login page in a function and call it.
eg.

```
def login() :    
    newuser_signup = input("New user? (y/n): ")
    if newuser_signup == "y":
        newuser_name = input("New Username: ")
        usernames.append(newuser_name)
        newuser_password = input("New Password: ")
        passwords.append(newuser_password
```

...

To call the function just write : `login()`

Comment: Syntax Error, needs edit.

Comment: Sorry- Didn't notice that.